# Need to sort first column by values in a dataset and then find average

Tags: sql, sorting

There are values in my data set. there are 3 columns.
column 1 has values 1,1,3,4,5,5,6,7,7,7,7. I need to sort the column and then apply average.
1,1 means two rows with index 1 and 1. i need to average values in rest of the columns i.e column 2 and column 3 for each row. 
similarly for data in 5,5 and so on. able to sort but cannot manage the average problem..

Comment: What brand of RDMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The ROW_NUMBER() should do the sorting for you and (col1+col2+col3)/3 should make it average for you. For nullable columns you will need to do some changes to the code.

```
SELECT t1.rownumber, (t1.col1 + t2.col2 + t3.col3)/3 as "AVG"
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col1 DESC) AS rownumber, col1 FROM MyTable) t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col2 ASC) AS rownumber, col2 FROM MyTable) as t2 on t1.rownumber = t2.rownumber
INNER JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col3 ASC) AS rownumber, col3 FROM MyTable) as t3 on t1.rownumber = t3.rownumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question sounds like a convoluted way of describing aggregation.  Is this what you want?

```
select col1, avg(col2), avg(col3)
from t
group by col1;
```

If you want the average on each row, then use window functions:

```
select col1,
       avg(col2) over (partition by (col1),
       avg(col3) over (partition by (col1)
from t;
```